# Cursor Positioning

Tags: java, cursor

I'm taking an Introductory Java class right now and for one of our first programs we created a program to calculate total sales and sales percentages of different stores within a franchise.
Now when I enter in the values for my variables, my cursor begins at the beginning of the line 
ex.

```
_Profits for shackA:(instead of here)
```

Here's the specific line that makes the console interface:

```
double shackA, shackB, shackC;
System.out.print("Profits for Shack A: ");
shackA = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Profits for Shack B: ");
shackB = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Profits for Shack C: ");
shackC = scan.nextDouble();
```

Is there any way to modify the starting position for a cleaner input?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
System.out.print("Profits for Shack A: ");
```

with

```
System.out.println("Profits for Shack A: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch to [`java.util.Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html), you could do something like this:

```
Console cons = System.console();
String inputA = cons.readLine("Profits for Shack A: ");
shackA = Double.parseDouble(inputA);
```

Of course, you'd need to do some error handling to handle the case that the user inputs "ABCD!!!" instead of a double.